# how to write this mysql query with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, pdo

I am writing a php login form and I would like to use PDO for db connection and writing my queries. Actually I am very new with PDO statements but in order to avoid sql injection, I would prefer to use it. I appreciate if someone could kindly help me to rewrite my query with PDO?

This is my code:

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: home.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
        $errflag = true;
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

I tried

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = :username and password = :password");`
```

and

```
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));`
```

but I don't know how I can rewrite the part related to "check if query was successful"

Comment: Have you actually declared a PDO connection type?

Comment: yes, I declared PDO connection. Now it works! Thanks for your time ans support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try -

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = :username and password = :password");
$stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if (!empty($result)) {

    # Login Successful    
    $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $result->mem_id;
    $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $result->username;
    $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $result->password;

    header("location: home.php");

} else {

    # Login failed
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
    $errflag = true;

        if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        header("location: index.php");
        }

}
```

Note that for Insert, Update, Delete etc you can use `$count = $stmt->rowCount();` followed by `if ($count > 0)` but as of yet it doesn't perform reliably with `SELECT`

Comment: thanks for yr help , I tried your solution, but when I insert user and pass it reload the login page again (instead of redirecting to home.php), I think maybe I have to change also the line related to this part! Do u have any idea?

Comment: I think the problem is this line: $member=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: Modified my answer as you seem a little confused - no more mysql_fetch_assoc required. Also removed your `session_regenerate_id` and `session_write_close` as they aren't needed for simple login scripts.

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot, it works now :) just could I ask you why you removed some lines such as **session_regenerate_id()** , **session_write_close()** or **exit()** ? thanks

Comment: `session_write_close()` is useful on a system with mulitple concurrent hits on SESSION data (such as using framesets, see [the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php), but is automaticlly done when a page finishes processing. And as you're only creating a session here for the first time, not needed. Same goes for regenerat_id. Exit was un-needed as your script was already finished when you called it. They're useful as breakpoints in debugging and error handling, it does not need called in every script.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `rowCount()` in this case to check:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = :username and password = :password");
$stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username,':password'=>$password));
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    // then select row has round rows
    $member = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
    session_write_close();
    header("location: home.php");
    exit();

}
```

Comment: This is not recommended if you check the PHP manual - 

`If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.`

Comment: @ghost: I tried iamgory solution, but when I insert user and password it reload the login page again! and this is php nnotice I receive in error.log: **Undefined index: mem_id in /var/www/login_exec.php on line 67, referer: http://localhost/index.php** and the same notice for username and password.. do you have any idea?

Comment: @mOna most likely that error is shown because of the flag `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, once its set, you need to call each row by its properties since it fetched objects instead of arrays

Comment: @mOna you need to access the properties to `->mem_id` and so on, instead of using `$member['mem_id']`

Comment: @Ghost: sorry I did not understand well, however I receive the same result when I try your code ( u used FETCH_ASSOC)..

Comment: @mOna i revised my answer, using fetchAll was nonsensical, check my answer, i just changed it to `->fetch()`

Comment: @mOna Remove *all* of your own code, *do not mix it* with mine or Ghosts. Either solution should work fine by themselves as standalone scripts. Can you include any error messages?